# python: creating a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a list of strings:

```
["dog", "cat" ,"boy", "cat", "car", "bus",....]
```

and I want to convert it into a dictionary like that:

```
{"dog": ["cat"], "cat":["boy","car"], "boy": ["cat"], "car":["bus"]....}
```

What is the best way to turn each string in the list to a key and the following string to the value as a list? 
sometimes I get few values with the same key so I want to put them together (like in the second index of the dictionary above).

Comment: How are you making the dict? the value is always the word on the right?

Comment: `"sometimes I get few values with the same key so I want to put them together"` Then what determines which words belong together?

Comment: yes.
I thought about creating an empty dictionary and adding the keys and values.

Comment: "boy" and "car" both come after "cat" so they sould be together

Comment: @user1073865: Actually it looks like there is no constant manner you create your dictionary. Make up your mind first and then tell us: 1) what are your requirements?, 2) how you would create the dictionary, step by step, to meet your requirements?

Comment: @user1073865: I have corrected part of your original question - please review it. It adds quotes around " `bus` ".

Comment: +1 to cancel downvotes-- question was not well worded but user has been very forthcoming with commons and I feel the downvotes are a little harsh now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
lst = ["dog", "cat" ,"boy", "cat", "car", "bus"]
pairs = zip(lst, lst[1:])     # [("dog", "cat"), ("cat", "boy"), ...]
d = {}
for k,v in pairs:
    d.setdefault(k, [])    # Set e.g. d["dog"] to [] if there is no d["dog"] yet
    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: +1 I love it! Beautiful way to solve the problem. Just one suggestion: I generally use `for var1, var2 in tuples:` when I have a list of tuples, makes the code more readable, doesn't it?

Comment: julio.alegria: Of course, I'd stupidly forgotten about unpacking tuples. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Indeed good, but we do not even know if it answers OP's question - he/she needs to make up his/her mind first (on the basis of what value is assigned to `cat` index in the resulting dictionary in OP's question I assume this is not answering his question).

Comment: It's hard to discern the pattern, but look carefully: "cat" appears twice; the first time, it is followed by "boy", and the second time, it is followed by "car". Thus the value entry is `["boy", "car"]`. It took me a few minutes to understand it, myself :-)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: You are right, I did not put much attention to deciphering his post and it looked as he really does not know what he wants. My bad. +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the obligatory [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) answer to go with the [`dict.setdefault`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330284/505154) and [`if key in dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8330278/505154) answers.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = ["dog", "cat" ,"boy", "cat", "car", "bus"]
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    d[a].append(b)
```

If this is for a very large list and memory efficiency is an issue you may want to use `izip` and `islice` from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

Comment: +1, learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you add error checking for not trying to add the element with index `len(mylist)`:

```
d = {}
for i,s in enumerate(mylist):
  if s in d:
    d[s].append(mylist[i+1])
  else:
    d[s] = [mylist[i+1]]
```

EDIT: need to use `s` as key.

Comment: this is not what the user asked, plus this will raise an `IndexError`

Comment: would fail when you access i+1 at the end of the list

Comment: If you catch the IndexError as I suggested in my response, it will exactly generate the desired `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this:

```
res = {}

for i in range(len(l) - 1):
     try:
         res[l[i]].append(l[i+1])
     except KeyError:
         res[l[i]] = [l[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an absolute, robust solution to your question since you said "sometimes I get few values with the same key".  How can we know which values to put with which key?

Here is a simple algorithm to put each element of the list as a key with the following element as the value:

```
my_list = sometimes I get few values with the same key
my_dict = dict([])
last = ''
init = 0
for a in my_list:
    if init == 0:
        init = 1
        last = a
        pass
    my_dict[last] = a
    last = a
```

Now your my_dict will contain all elements of your list as a key, with the following element as the value.

Hope this helps.